# Is there a way to EXPAND a group in Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

In the Layers panel, Photoshop has a dropdown option to 'Collapse All Groups'. Is there a reverse option to expand one or all groups or a way to do it in Javascript?

Comment: Haha, yes it's unfortunate that people don't read the question before acting on it, while javascript based solution might work here but I've never done that level of scripting , you may try [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5552/is-it-possible-to-collapse-expand-all-groups-in-photoshop-layers-panel) instead

Comment: @Viney Thanks for the link and solidarity. Unfortunately that answer won't work in an action as 'Collapse All Groups will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, answer is derived from

https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/expand-collapse-a-group-via-javascript/td-p/7286289/page/2?page=1%3F

```
var groupname = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name // name of active layer 
var idungroupLayersEvent = stringIDToTypeID( "ungroupLayersEvent" ); // ungroup layer event 

var desc14 = new ActionDescriptor();

var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );

var ref13 = new ActionReference();

var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
ref13.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
desc14.putReference( idnull, ref13 );

executeAction( idungroupLayersEvent, desc14, DialogModes.NO );

var idMk = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " ); // make action , note the space
var desc15 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );

var ref14 = new ActionReference();

var idlayerSection = stringIDToTypeID( "layerSection" );
ref14.putClass( idlayerSection );
desc15.putReference( idnull, ref14 );
var idFrom = charIDToTypeID( "From" );

var ref15 = new ActionReference();

var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " ); // <-- note the space
var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
ref15.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
desc15.putReference( idFrom, ref15 );

executeAction( idMk, desc15, DialogModes.NO );
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name = groupname // recall group name
```

Answer (score 1):

Any hoops, to collapse all groups just use Scriptlistner code:

```
function collapse_all_groups()
{
  // =======================================================
  var idcollapseAllGroupsEvent = stringIDToTypeID( "collapseAllGroupsEvent" );
  var desc46 = new ActionDescriptor();
  executeAction( idcollapseAllGroupsEvent, desc46, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

And there doesn't appear to be a "expandAllGroupsEvent"

However, I eventually found the [answer here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/is-there-a-quot-collapse-all-groups-layersets-quot-shortcut/td-p/11082982?page=1)

```
function openAllLayerSets(parent)
{
    for (var setIndex = 0; setIndex < parent.layerSets.length; setIndex++) 
    {
        try
        {
          app.activeDocument.activeLayer = parent.layerSets[setIndex].layers[0];
        }
        catch(e)
        {
          alert(e + app.activeDocument.activeLayer);
        }
        openAllLayerSets(parent.layerSets[setIndex]);
    }
}

openAllLayerSets(app.activeDocument);
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work unfortunately. I get a 'Error 1302: No such element' for line 5.

Comment: Weird. Have you tried creating a small psd with a couple of layers and put those layers in a group? Then re-try the script. I've added a try /catch so you might be able to find the layer that's causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

this works in UXP JavaScript land in Ps 23.5.0
showing both getting the expanded state and switching/or toggling it; to expand all currently I'd simply walk the layers properties of group layers (layers where `layer.kind === 'group'`) from the desired starting point (or `photoshop.app.activeDocument.layers`) as I don't know if there are more options applicable to this approach

```
function toggleGroupLayer(_id=-1){
    const photoshop = require('photoshop');
    photoshop.action.batchPlay([

        { _obj: "multiGet", _target: {_ref: "layer", _id}, extendedReference: [[
           "layerSectionExpanded"
        ]] }
    ], {}).then(([{layerSectionExpanded}])=>{

    console.log(`before toggling:`,{_id, layerSectionExpanded});
    layerSectionExpanded = !layerSectionExpanded;
    return photoshop.core.executeAsModal(function _executeAsModal(context, descriptor){
        return photoshop.action.batchPlay([{
            _obj: "set",
            _target: [{ _ref: "property", _property: "layerSectionExpanded" }, { _ref: "layer", _id }],
            to: layerSectionExpanded
        }], {}).then(res=>{
            return descriptor;
        }).catch(console.error);
    },
    { commandName: 'toggle group layer expanded', descriptor: {layerSectionExpanded, _id} }
    );

    }).then(console.log).catch(console.error);

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure what you mean by 'walk the layers properties of group layers...'

Comment: group layers have child layers, as in `layer.layers = [childLayer,...]` and those can also be group layers, so walking/recursing through them to collapse/expand all isn't accounted for here in the example; if this answer works please accept/upvote it as you see fit