# How to close a layer folder on Photoshop using CEP/ExtendScript/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script, adobe-extension

I'm developing an extension in Photoshop and I need to close a layers folder (containing a lot of information) to make the layers view cleaner.
I haven't found anything in the Photoshop documentation and nothing on the forums.

From :

[image]

To :

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: [google is your friend, the answer is here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/expand-collapse-a-group-via-javascript/td-p/7286289)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't typing the right terms in the search bar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Ghoul Fool for finding this thread :

https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/expand-collapse-a-group-via-javascript/td-p/7286289

Answer (score 1):

this works in Ps 23.5

```
photoshop.core.executeAsModal(function _executeAsModal(){
        return photoshop.action.batchPlay([{
            _obj: "set",
            _target: [{ _ref: "property", _property: "layerSectionExpanded" }, { _ref: "layer", _id: 1234 }],
            to: true // true to open/expand, false to collapse/close
        }], {}).then(res=>{
            return 'should be expanded now';
        });
    },
    { commandName: 'open/expand group layer' }
).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

related: [Is there a way to EXPAND a group in Photoshop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380294/is-there-a-way-to-expand-a-group-in-photoshop) https://gist.github.com/JimaDobes/371fcaf0d8f61fb5d1175d54e85209c7